# Convert image to utf8 base64 encoded string

Tags: react-native, utf-8, base64

I currently have an image uri from the expo impage picker library:

```
    return ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        allowsEditing: false,
        base64: true,
        quality: 1,
    })
```

I need to then convert that selected image to a base 64 string. I tried using RNFS library to do this conversion:

```
const imageBase64 = await RNFS.readFile(image, 'base64').then(res => {
   return res
});
```

but the resulting string does not match image encoding I see here: https://www.base64-image.de/

I think I need to encode the image using utf-8 - is there some way I can do this?

Comment: *the resulting string does not match image encoding I see here* - it's quite vague what *does not match* actually means.  The result (at least a part of it) should be included in the question.

Comment: the entirety of the string contents differ - should I copy and paste both strings into paste.com or something? They are massive